# Deserialize XML to object doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, deserialization

I have a XML as below. I want to convert this to c# object . I tried modyfying but could not get it working.

```
<SLVGeoZone-array>
   <SLVGeoZone>
    <id>19</id>
    <type>geozone</type>
    <name>60_OLC_SC</name>
    <namesPath>GeoZones/60_OLC_SC</namesPath>
    <idsPath>1/19</idsPath>
    <childrenCount>0</childrenCount>
   </SLVGeoZone>
  </SLVGeoZone-array>
```

I have a written a sample c# code and it doesn't work:

```
[Serializable]
public class SLVGeoZone
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("namespath")]
    public string namespath { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("idspath")]
    public string idspath { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("childrencount")]
    public string childrencount { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("SLVGeoZone-array")]
public class SLVGeoZone-array
{
    [XmlArray("SLVGeoZone-array")]
    [XmlArrayItem("SLVGeoZone", typeof(SLVGeoZone))]
    public SLVGeoZone[] Car { get; set; }
}
```

And in the form:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarCollection));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
cars = (CarCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Can someone suggest what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Does it throw an exception? Does it return an empty object? Those an unspeakable horror warp in from the elder dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `SLVGeoZone-array` is not a valid class name in C#

   ```
   [Serializable()]
   [XmlRoot("SLVGeoZone-array")]
   public class SLVGeoZones
   {
       [XmlElement("SLVGeoZone")]
       public SLVGeoZone[] Cars { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. `XmlElement` attribute values have to be exactly the same as element names in XML file. Yours are not.

   ```
   [Serializable()]
   public class SLVGeoZone
   {
       [XmlElement("id")]
       public string id { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("type")]
       public string type { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("name")]
       public string name { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("namesPath")]
       public string namespath { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("idsPath")]
       public string idspath { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("childrenCount")]
       public string childrencount { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. What is `CarCollection` and why are you trying to deserialize your XML as `CarCollection` instead of classes you've shown here?

   ```
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SLVGeoZones));
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Input.txt");
   var items = (SLVGeoZones)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
   reader.Close();
   ```